# Running async setup code for cargo integration test

Tags: rust, integration-testing, actix-web

In my project, the main binary is a server (using actix_web) and I want the integration tests to hit the API (to test the server and serde json) rather than directly call the route handlers from the tests.

I see previous answers that use `std::sync::Once` to simulate a setup code that gets called only once.

My issue is that the tests are `async` and setup code itself is `async fn` and adding a `#[actix_web::test]` or `spawn` in the setup function creates a runtime inside runtime when called from the tests.

How do I make sure that server code runs only once for the integration tests.

Comment: Maybe with [`tokio::sync::OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Jmb. This helped resolve my issue. I'm able to run the async setup code only once.